# jquery appendo plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am facing problem using jquery appendo plugin, i have cloned the fields but I want to populate a text field based on what i select from a drop downlist, i have a drop down list of products and when i select one, the text field next to it must be filled with the corresponding rate. I was able to activate an ajax event on changing the dropdown list which brought data from the server side but i'm not able to populate the adjacent text field. Here's my code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript" src="jquery.appendo.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.product').change(function(){
            //ajax call and receiving the data but after getting the data from server how to populate the rate text field
        });
        var id = 0;
        var append = $('#objid').appendo({
        allowDelete: true,
        copyHandlers: true      
    });


});
</script>
```

and this is my html part.

```
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <table id="objid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Client:</th>
                <th>Product:</th>
                <th>Rate:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
        <td>
            <select class="product" name="product[]">
                <option value="">---Select---</option>
                <option value="web_designing">Web Designing</option>
                <option value="hosting">Hosting</option>
                <option value="domain">Domain</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate[]"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code's part:

> ```
>     $('.product').change(function(){
>         //ajax call and receiving the data but after getting the data from server how to populate the rate text field
>     });
> ```

You can add value to the text field by using this code:

> ```
>     $('.product').change(function(){
>         //ajax call and receiving the data but after getting the data from server how to populate the rate text field
>         var value = ajax_received_value;
>         var $this = $(this);
>         $this.parent().next().children().val(value);
>     });
> ```